# How can i not count the spaces between my string

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have, p.e, this string: ' I love python  ' and I want to convert all the spaces to '_'. My problem is that I also need to delete the outside spaces so I dont finish with the result: '_I_love_python__' and more like this 'I_love_python'
I searched and found out that I can develop it with a single line of code `mystring.strip().replace(" ", "_")` which is unfortunaly is sintax that I cant apply in my essay.
So what I landed with was this:

```
frase= str(input('Introduza: '))

aux=''


for car in frase:
    if car==' ':
        car='_'
        aux+=car
    else:
        aux+=car



print(aux)
```

My problem now is on deleting those outside spaces. What I thought about was runing another for i in in the start and another on the final of the string and to stop until they found a non space caracter. But unfortunaly I havent been able to do that...

Apreciate all the help you can suply!

Comment: `aux = frase.strip().replace(" ", "_")` You have to strip the outside spaces *first*, then replace what are left with `_`.

Comment: @chepner, OP says he can't use that.

Comment: The reason given for not using that makes no sense.

Comment: Are you allowed to use regex?

Comment: Can we get more details about what you're allowed to use? Can you do `frase = frase.strip()` to get rid of the outside spaces?

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this platform and only viewed this comment right now :). Fortunaly I was able to use anything I wanted in the essay. Thank you for all your submitions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with following solution:

You iterate over the string, but instead of replacing the space with underscore as soon as it appears, you store the amount of spaces encountered. Then, once a non-space-character is reached, you add the amount of spaces found to the string. So if the string ends with lots of spaces, it will never reach a non-space-character and therefore never add the underscores.

For cutting off the spaces at the beginning, I just added a condition to add the underscores being: "Have I encountered a non-space-character before?"

Here is the code:

```py
text = "   I love   python    e  "

out = ""

string_started = False
underscores_to_add = 0
for c in text:
    if c == " ":
        underscores_to_add += 1
    else:
        if string_started:
            out += "_" * underscores_to_add
        underscores_to_add = 0
        string_started = True
        out += c

print(out)  # prints "I_love___python____e"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! From all the submitions yours contains vocabulary which I know and use. Once again thank you for spending some time with my problem! Cheers m8!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following trick to remove leading and trailing spaces in your string:

```
s = ' I love python   '

ind1 = min(len(s) if c == ' ' else n for n, c in enumerate(s))
ind2 = max(0 if c == ' ' else n for n, c in enumerate(s))

s = ''.join('_' if c == ' ' else c for c in s[ind1:ind2 + 1])

print('*', s, '*', sep='')
```

Output:

```
*I_love_python*
```

Answer (score -1):

#### If you are not allowed to use strip() method

```
def find(text):
    for i, s in enumerate(text):
        if s !=  " ":
            break
    return i

text = "   I love   python    e  "
text[find(text):len(text)-find(text[::-1])].replace(" ","_")

texts = ["   I love   python    e  ","I love   python    e"," I love   python    e","I love   python    e ", "I love   python    e"]
for text in texts:
    print (text[find(text):len(text)-find(text[::-1])].replace(" ","_"))
```

output:

`I_love___python____e
I_love___python____e
I_love___python____e
I_love___python____e
I_love___python____e`

- Given a string `find` will find the first non space character in the string
- Use `find` to find the first nonspace character and the last nonspace character
- Get the substring using above found indices
- Replace all spaces with _ in the above substring

Comment: Curious to know why it is down voted and what my mistake is :) It will  help me in my future answers :)